# Get value from Url in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Hi I am trying to make code for array in php but didn't get any solution please help me

```
{ if !in_array($productgroup.gid,array(69,68,27,31,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,{php}echo $cid;{/php})) }

<option value="{$productgroup.gid}"{if $gid eq $productgroup.gid} selected="selected"{/if}>{$productgroup.name}</option>

{/if}
```

http://demo.qualispace.com/shop/cart.php?gid=70&country=USA&os=Linux&idd=30&name=RH

Answer (score 0):

why are you writing php in smarty. it is a bad practice. 
Also try to do something like this.

```
{if in_array($needle, $array)}
```

another point is you are doing it wrong here.

```
array(69,68,27,31,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,{php}echo $cid;{/php})
```

its like following in php,

```
array(1,2,echo 3)
```

when using smarty first preference should be given to smarty variables.

Comment: need solution from my question

Comment: the solution is there. use in array like this, `{if in_array($needle, $array)}` and don't do echo. also populate `$array` in PHP.

Comment: but how can i take values from url and put into arrays in below linkhttp://demo.qualispace.com/shop/cart.php?gid=70&country=USA&os=Linux&idd=30&name=RH i want idd values and paas into arrays

Comment: create this array `array(69,68,27,31,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,{php}echo $cid;{/php})` in php and also get the URL in php and pass it to smarty. smarty is supposed to be the presentation layer only. you should get values only in PHP.

Comment: i am beginner to smarty so how can i create and assign will u please write steps

Comment: @Jammess Have you read documentation [DOC](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.tpl) ?

Comment: so in php create an array `$temp = array(69,68,27,31,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77);` get the value of URL in `$cid`. then `$temp[] = $cid; $smarty->assign('smarty_array', $temp);` and in smarty  `{ if !in_array($productgroup.gid,$smarty_array) }`

Comment: following error shows Fatal error: Call to a member function assign() on a non-object in /home/demoqual/public_html/shop/templates_c/%%F1^F10^F102D2A1%%products-prodslider.tpl.php on line 189

Comment: use the your smarty object. $smarty here is the smarty object.

Comment: { if !in_array($productgroup.gid,array(69,68,27,31,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,{php}echo $cid;{/php})) }

<option value="{$productgroup.gid}"{if $gid eq $productgroup.gid} selected="selected"{/if}>{$productgroup.name}</option>

{/if} how can i pass url variable insted of php code in in_array

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51396/discussion-between-junaid-atique-and-jammess)

Comment: come to the chat link above.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer using

{ if !in_array($productgroup.gid,array(69,68,27,31,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,$smarty.get.idd)) }

{$productgroup.name}

{/if}